# if i click 2nd child div i have to change first child div class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="../" class="navbar-brand logo">
            <img src="../images/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar-collapse menu menu-horizontal collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">test</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When my child div class as "collapse in" I have to add the class above button class as a "navbar-toggle-active".

When my child div class as "collapse" I have to add the class above button class as a "navbar-toggle".

Comment: Can you make code snippet?

Comment: do you want to change the class of "navbar-header" upon clikcing on "navbarCollapse"?

Comment: thanks for your replay Yannick Meeus  u can check boot strap menu there and need same functionality http://codepen.io/ramanavem/pen/bNxdLV